# Calculate hamming distance of bloom filters in c?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, hamming-distance, bitwise-and, bloom-filter

I need to compare two equal sized bloom filters **BF1** and **BF2** for their similarity using **hamming distance** which expresses the distance between the two sets as Bloom Distance

> **B(BF1,BF2)=one(BF1 & BF2)/SIZEOF(BF1)**
>   Where the **one()** function counts number of set bits in the ANDed bloom filter.

I adopted this formula from [Path similarity evaluation using Bloom filters](https://research.csiro.au/ng/wp-content/uploads/sites/106/2016/08/fullText.study_451205.pdf) section 3(page 4. Similarity metrics).

I have implemented the following c code to do it but it definitely is not working.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
const int BF_LEN= 1024;

char *BF1;//=malloc(BF_LEN*sizeof(char));
char *BF2;//=malloc(BF_LEN*sizeof(char));
char *buf;//=malloc(BF_LEN*sizeof(char));
char *buf_ptr=NULL;
int set_bits_count=0;
float similarity=0.0;

u_int32_t NumberOfSetBits(u_int32_t i)
{
    return (((((i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333) + (((i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555)) & 0x33333333) + (((i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555)) >> 2) & 0x33333333) >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}

void main()
{
    BF1=malloc(BF_LEN*sizeof(char));
    BF2=malloc(BF_LEN*sizeof(char));
    buf=malloc(BF_LEN*sizeof(char));
 //Edit2:initialize them to 0
for(int j=0;j<BF_LEN;j++)    
        {
            BF1[j]='\0';
            BF2[j]='\0';
            buf[j]='\0';
        }
    BF1="BF1 is filled with some characters";
    BF2="BF2 is filled with some characters and more";

    for(int j=0; j<BF_LEN; j++)
    {
        buf[j]=BF1[j]&BF2[j];
    }

    buf_ptr=buf;

    for(int m=0; m<BF_LEN; m++) //This is for the **one()** function
        set_bits_count+=NumberOfSetBits(*buf_ptr++);

    similarity=1-set_bits_count/(float)BF_LEN;
    printf("%.2f",similarity);
//Edit1: Following Comments
    free(BF1);
    free(BF2);
    free(buf);
}
```

**NumberOfSetBits()** Adopted from [Set bit counter](https://gist.github.com/pbassut/9a377d82a4399ebe4c8e20eeefbe02a8)

Comment: What results are you getting? Best guess you need to cast one of set_bits_count or BF_LEN to a float before doing the division else you'll get integer division.

Comment: @Rup I corrected it as your comment. Still no correct result.

Comment: Not related to your problem::You have memory leak when overwrite `malloc` with  `BF1="BF1 is filled with some characters";`

Comment: @kiranBiradar how do I fix it? I am new to c.

Comment: Then you'll have to debug this yourself sorry. Are BF1 and BF2 initialised correctly? (I assume the string assignments here are for demonstration purposes only, that's not what you're actually doing? If it is, should make sure the memory past the end of the strings is zeroed up to BF_LEN. Or if you are populating the malloced memory make sure you explicitly zero it first.) Is buf what you'd expect? Does NumberOfSetBits count up the bits in buf, or a small example, correctly? Is set_bits_count what you'd expect to get the correct result?

Comment: Kiran's point is you're not free()ing any of your buffers, and particularly you're reassigning the BF1 pointer to your constant string and losing the pointer you just malloced (as above I assume that's not what you're actually doing?). If that's the end of the program then it's not really a problem: the OS will reclaim all allocated memory. If you are continuing on to do more stuff you should call free() on the pointers you get back from malloc().

Comment: @Rup Yes, the string assignments are for demonstration only.

Comment: Your latest edit: you should then strcpy the strings into the buffer rather than reassign the pointers with =. Then you'll have the strings in the buffers padded with zeroes.

Comment: Hamming distance is usually the popcnt of the XOR of two bit strings, not the popcnt of their AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a try with this code. Hamming distance is the population count with XOR:

```
 void hamming()
 {
    static const unsigned int BF_LEN = 1024;

    char BF1[BF_LEN];
    char BF2[BF_LEN];

    unsigned int set_bits_count = 0;
    float similarity = 0.0f;

    memset(BF1,'\0',BF_LEN);
    memset(BF2,'\0',BF_LEN);
    strcpy(BF1, "BF1 is filled with some characters");
    strcpy(BF2, "BF2 is filled with some characters and more");

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < BF_LEN; j += sizeof(T_Uint32))
    {
        set_bits_count += hammingDistance(*(T_Uint32*)&BF1[j], *(T_Uint32*)&BF2[j]);
    }


    similarity = 1.0f - set_bits_count/(float)BF_LEN;
    printf("%.2f", similarity);
}

//Reference: P. Wegner, Comm. ACM, Vol. 3, Issue 5, 1960. 
T_Uint getNrOfBitsSet(T_Uint32 bits)
{     
  T_Uint bitsSet = 0;

  while (bits)
  {
    bits &= bits - 1; // clears the least significant bit set
    ++bitsSet;
  }
  return bitsSet;
}

T_Uint hammingDistance(T_Uint32 a, T_Uint32 b)
{
    return getNrOfBitsSet(a^b);
}
```